# Submitting form using mailto

Tags: android, forms, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am having an issue submitting with my form which I have built using jquery mobile and uploaded onto my android tablet using Phonegap build.

The script I am using is

```
<script>
function formSubmit()
{
            document.getElementById("SiteVisit").action ="mailto:pja@bresnan.net?cc=" + document.getElementById("COC_Received_By").value + "&subject=Site%20Visit%20Form";
            document.getElementById("SiteVisit").submit();

}
</script>

<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="SiteVisit" id="SiteVisit">
```

I keep getting an Application Error that "The Protocol isn't Supported"

I am not real code savvy...can someone please help me out with this one

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just submit a form like this. Usually, on a normal web browser, you can't - you need the browser to be configured to use email. This is likely a browser configuration issue.

If you want things sent by email you can use one of the email plugins for PGB.

You set up your form to send its information to the email program. There are two ways to do it - 1. the user fills in a form and when they click Send all the info is sent to the email app and the user has to click Send again. 2. You just have the email option.

I use version 1 because, as it's a form, you can have the email pre-populated with the options from the Form. E.g. If you have a star rating you can pass the value from the form to the email. The heading of the email, for example, would be "Service Rating 5/5" or "Service Rating 3/5". Iyswim.

Comment: I have been trying to get a plugin to work but nothing happens. I have added <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.0" /> to my config file and added the following script but to my code but no bueno <script> function formSubmit() { document.getElementById("SiteVisit").action = window.plugin.Email.open ({ to: ['pja@bresnan.net'], cc: ['document.getElementById("COC_Received_By").value'], subject: 'Site Visit Form', body: 'document.getElementById("SiteVisit")', }) document.getElementById("SiteVisit").submit(); } </script>

Comment: You have to follow the instructions in the documentation for that plugin.

Comment: That's what I have been trying to do...I guess I just don't understand what they are saying - like I said, I am really new at the whole phonegap build plugin thing and the instructions are not all that clear to me

Comment: Go through it slowly. Make sure you read the bits about Build and that you're using the correct versions of Build and the plugin for compatibility.